# Wordpress - How to get a specific posts page number URL?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is it possible to get a specific **posts** page number URL inside an article? For instance, when in the normal loop, the function `get_pagenum_link(3)` will retrieve something like `http://mysite.com/blog/page/3/`

The problem is, when on an article `is_single() == true` that same function does not return the paged results. I understand I'm currently out of the loop, but is there any way I can work around that ?

Comment: Can you explain the use?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;

$url = $post ? get_permalink($post->ID) : '';
```